# Simple 2 Boolean Efficiency

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

Just a quick one guys - y'know when your brain hurts just looking at something. Just seeing if there is a "better" way to do this in terms of boolean logic.

```
private RegenerationType AccquireRegenerationState (int floor, int playerFloor)
{
    bool entranceExists = (floorBlocks[floor].doorBlocks.Count != 0) ? true : false;

    if (floor + 1 == playerFloor || !floorBlocks[floor + 1].isVisited)
    {
        if (entranceExists)
        {
            return RegenerationType.Still;
        }
        else
        {
            return RegenerationType.Limit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (entranceExists)
        {
            return RegenerationType.Prime;
        }
        else
        {
            return RegenerationType.Full;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a nice place for such questions http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @klappvisor This question in its current form is not suitable for that site. Please keep the different site rules in mind. While on *this* site, minimal code to demonstrate the problem is a good thing, on *that* site, complete working code is a good thing, and this is not complete working code.

Comment: You can remove that useless ternary, the result of a comparison is already a `bool`.

Comment: all "else" statements can be omitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's the best you can achieve. Of course, assuming that you maintain code readability and clearness:

```
private RegenerationType AccquireRegenerationState (int floor, int playerFloor)
{
    var entranceExists = floorBlocks[floor].doorBlocks.Count != 0;

    var whatever = floor + 1 == playerFloor || !floorBlocks[floor + 1].isVisited;

    if (whatever)
    {
        return entranceExists ? RegenerationType.Still : RegenerationType.Limit;
    }
    else
    {
        return entranceExists ? RegenerationType.Prime : RegenerationType.Full;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea that's it, thanks I just didn't know if I was derping and there was a better way. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool entranceExists = (floorBlocks[floor].doorBlocks.Count != 0);
return
    (floor + 1 == playerFloor || !floorBlocks[floor + 1].isVisited)?
    (entranceExists? RegenerationType.Still: RegenerationType.Limit):
    (entranceExists? RegenerationType.Prime: RegenerationType.Full);
```

Comment: Is this an improvement? If venture that the longhand in the original question would be considerably easier to maintain than this.

Comment: @spender It could be a matter of taste/preferences. For me in that concrete case the code is easier _to read_ (not sure about _to maintain_). But maybe I just like the ternary operator :).